# Get list of available timezones in fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to rebuild something similar to the below link using ReactJS.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone-demo

they have also provided a very good example showing how they got the list.

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001

My issue is I am not sure how to get the timezone names so that I can implement rest of the features in my app. Because I am using reactjs I cannot do it like they showed it in the demo.

```
 FullCalendar.requestJson('GET', 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-timezones.json', {}, function(timeZones) {
    timeZones.forEach(function(timeZone) {
      var optionEl;

      if (timeZone !== 'UTC') { // UTC is already in the list
        optionEl = document.createElement('option');
        optionEl.value = timeZone;
        optionEl.innerText = timeZone;
        timeZoneSelectorEl.appendChild(optionEl);
      }
    });
  }, function() {
    // failure
  });
```

and this is what my code looks like, I took it from the official documentation

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import { toMoment } from '@fullcalendar/moment'; // only for formatting
import momentTimezonePlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment-timezone';

let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ momentTimezonePlugin ],
  timeZone: 'America/New_York',
  events: [
    { start: '2018-09-01T12:30:00Z' }, // will be shifted to America/New_York
    { start: '2018-09-01T12:30:00+XX:XX' }, // will be shifted to America/New_York
    { start: '2018-09-01T12:30:00' } // will be parsed as America/New_York
  ],
  dateClick: function(arg) {
    // millisecond value is correctly in America/New_York
    console.log(arg.date.valueOf())

    // use the plugin for manipulation and formatting
    let m = toMoment(arg.date, calendar)
    console.log(m.format()) // something like '2018-09-01T12:30:00-05:00'
  }
});
```

Here's what the app structure looks like, I got this from the official fullcalendar website.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone

So my question is how would I implement the dropdown in my react application? I'm importing momentTimezonePlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment-timezone', Is it possible I can get the list from the plugin? I have not found anything useful when I tried to console log and see what's inside the plugin that I imported.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know react, but I'm sure you can find a tutorial or example somewhere showing how to fetch some JSON data from a URL and bind it to a drop-down list. Because that's all that's happening with the drop-down list really.

Comment: @ADyson do you mean I can fetch from 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-timezones.json' just like the above example or is there a way I can get the Names directly from moment library.

Comment: I see no reason why not. It's just an AJAX request. Or yes maybe you could get it from a library...check the documentation of your library of choice, and/or do some googling.

Comment: Okay thanks, I just wanted to make sure that I only import the time zones supported by FullCalendar, I will use the demo-timezones.json itself as it is coming from the official website

Comment: Fullcalendar supports all the timezones in existence as far as I know. Certainly at least all the ones which are known by whatever browser it's running in (as already mentioned in the fullCalendar timezone documentation)